# Unable to open XPS from PlanAhead(Xilinx ISE 14.3)

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am unable to open Xilinx Platform Studio(XPS) from PlanAhead. It shows me following error messages:

[image: XpsGuiSessionLock]

[image: Error]

I have not opened multiple sessions of it. I have also removed the write protection for that folder. But still I get this error all the time!

Any solution? (Or should I open the .xmp file from the folder and then generate the netlist?)

Thank you.

Comment: Does opening the project from XPS works? You may want to upgrade to 14.7, it's the last (as in end-of-line) version of ISE and they fixed a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually the problem with installing WebPack version and trying to copy full version license.

Removed the Webpack version and installed Embedded edition and copied full license.

It works fine now!